# "Node 8 The Right way" - why the ouput of zmq-filer-req-loop.js interleaved?

Tags: node.js, zeromq

In the book "Node 8 the right way", in section "Trading Synchronicity for Scale", I thought that the code in the main **`zmq-filer-req-loop.js`** file has to be completed before any callbacks can be called. Which means all the requests have to be sent and the main file is completed, before the first callback of the first request is called. So I don’t understand how the output of request and response are interleaved, as demonstrated in the author's output:

```
Sending request 1
Sending request 2
Receive response (from callback)
Sending request 3
Sending request 4
Receive response (from callback)
```

Expected output:

```
Sending request 1
Sending request 2
Sending request 3
Sending request 4
Receive response 1
Receive response 2
Receive response 3
Receive response 4
```

Please help explain this, as I may misunderstand something here.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You might be already aware that StackOverflow Community encourages users to post high quality questions using **MCVE-code** format, i.e. using a **M**inimum-**C**omplete-**V**erifiable-**E**xample - i.e. a code, that can be re-run ( incl. inputs + data ) + that demonstrates a claimed problem + that can verify a fix-up / correction on its own + is posted explicitly here ( not derrogating Community members to go  somewhere else for the MCVE-code, nor missing completely ). **You might review the post and decide to revise your post, so as to meet this Community standard**